# Capped Brightness in Win 8 / Bootcamp

Tags: mac, windows-8, boot-camp, brightness

So I just installed windows 8 on my mac (osx Lion, late 2011 mbp) via bootcamp, and I have all of the drivers installed. However, my maximum brightness seems to be capped by Windows, because it is not letting me get anywhere near my monite's maximum brightness. I tried updating my drivers but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to wait until the Bootcamp drivers are updated by Apple.

Comment: is their any way to circumvent this, because it was working before I installed the drivers

Comment: It was working before with Windows 8 and magically stop working?

Comment: The problem seems to be with ambient light sensor. Instead of adjusting the brightness to match the ambient light, it puts a cap on the MAX brightness to the level that it wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with adaptive brightness. You can disable it by following these instructions: http://www.howtogeek.com/107173/disable-windows-8s-adaptive-brightness-to-fix-dark-screen-problems/